# How to solve gradle installation error using sdkman

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, gradle, sdkman

```
Has anyone experienced this problem?

When trying to install gradle 4.4 the following error is displayed:
```

user@test:~$ sdk install gradle 4.4

Downloading: gradle 4.4

In progress...

Warning: Failed to open /home/user/.sdkman/tmp/gradle-4.4.headers.tmp
curl: (23) Failed writing received data to disk/application
mv: unable to get status '/home/user/.sdkman/tmp/gradle-4.4.bin': Missing file or directory

```
I removed and reinstalled SDKMAN several times and was unsuccessful


user@test:~$ sdk version

SDKMAN 5.16.0
---
Ubuntu v20.04
---
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 6):

This is because maybe you are using curl installed from snap. Try use curl from apt:

```
$ sudo snap remove curl
$ sudo apt install curl
```

Answer (score 0):

If the issue persists after curl has been reinstalled from apt as mentioned in the answer by @djafta, try setting the sdkman_beta_channel to false in ~/.sdkman/etc/config, then run:

$ sdk selfupdate force

By default sdkman beta channel is set to true by default. The stable release does not have the mentioned issue, so this should resolve the issue.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).